# How can I know if oatmeal is with milk or water?

Tags: food, water

At the cafeteria in my workplace, they serve oatmeal.

I like oatmeal, but not with milk.

How I can check if it is with milk or water without tasting it? There is nobody to ask.

Comment: Have you asked a collegue (who tried the oatmeal) for their opinion?

Comment: usually I eat alone

Comment: Food for thought for anyone with the chemistry chops to answer, but I wonder if the milk wouldn't have enough fat in it (assuming it's not skim) to  use some sort fat soluble test chemical in it.

Comment: "There is nobody to ask." How can this be? Even if it's a self-serve cafeteria, someone had to make the oatmeal and put it out.

Comment: @barbecue, should I go to the kitchen?

Comment: Yes, if you really want to know.

Comment: If you don't have access to go to the kitchen itself, then speak to the person who refills the food in the cafeteria and ask them. If they don't know the answer, they can ask someone else.

Comment: so, every day I should look for person, who can reply on this question? I'd better won't eat at all.

Comment: @Alex I'd assume they stick to a pretty regular recipie. You could atleast ask them "do you always make it with milk/water?" that way you know whatever they use will always be used.

Comment: If it's a cafeteria, they are not going to randomly change their recipes from one day to the next. They will have a pre-planned menu, and they need to order food in advance of when it is served, so they won't make arbitrary changes to the recipes.

Comment: actually I asked today, it's on water and if you want a milk you can add it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Colour** and **Smell**.

Oatmeal with milk is always whitish than oatmeal with water.

[image: water oatmeal]
[image: milk oatmeal]

The left one is with water and the right one is with milk. Colour shade will vary with the type of milk and sometimes people use the combination of milk and water both.

Also milk Oatmeal always smells different, so you can smell it too.

Comment: yes, I understand that with milk it should be whiter, but actually color is something in the middle, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Alex Then it can be mixture of both. But you can smell

Comment: ok, will try next time